# How can i install Mysql or any database and how can i use it via sublime text 2

Tags: mysql, sublimetext2

I bought a new mac. I want to install any database and want to use it with sublime text 2.
I tried installing mysql via sublime text by the following:

tools->command palette->package control-> install package->db1

then it shows db1 error.

Included the below is the code in mysql.sublimebuild

```
{
    "cmd": ["/usr/include/php/ext/mysqli", "-u", "root", "-e", "source $file"],
    "selector": "/Users/jibinkuriakose/Desktop/code/test.sql"
}
```

then it shows `[Errno 13] Permission denied`

What should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with Mac or Sublime Text 2 (though I know that it's old and you should probably upgrade to version 3), but it seems like you are trying to install support for the MySQL extension for PHP.

- [If you want to install the MySQL database server itself, you should probably follow these directions from MySQL.com](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/osx-installation-pkg.html).
- If you want to install PHP with the MySQL extension, you should probably use [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/), as PHP.net do not have a Mac installation package, then after installing Homebrew itself (directions are available on their website linked above), [you should follow the instructions here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php).

After that, you should be able to use Sublime Text to write PHP code that accesses MySQL and then run it.